# Create Multiple Fragments Dynamically for Dynamic Tabs

Tags: android, fragment

I have a requirement and I do not know how to accomplish this. Can you guys help me out to get this done. Below is what the flow is

I have a Main Category list, user can tap to get sub categories (fetch from server) and based on the result I am displaying a list of subcategories with their child category as well. Next I am creating tabs based on the child categories.

Now my problem is creating fragments for that number of tabs. Childs can be from 1 to n number, so I would like to know the best way to create fragments dynamically. Once each fragment I have to display a list of items that would be fetched from server.

Thank you

Comment: You can use for loop. Perform for loop for n times and in each itaration you can create tab and fragment

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following code snap**

*You will need to create corresponding layout xml*

```
    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private List<Fragment>  fragments;
    ArrayList<String> Titles;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

        Titles= new ArrayList<String>();
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles, fragments);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        for (int i=0;i<numoffragments;i++){
                fragments.add(new DemoFragment());

            }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

         }
```

*You may need to do some more adjustments to get the **numoffragments** you will be using and also you have to make a fragment that can be used for all the childs*

*Hope this wil help.*

Comment: Thanks..  I am already doing this.. Can you please explain in detail about "Fragment that can be used for all the childs" ..

Comment: You can make a common fragment with common layout which can show the informations u want to show